# Track a process using htop

Tags: htop, nice

I have a process that runs for while gets killed and restarts itself for every 15 seconds and I want to track the nice value of it how to do it using htop .I can track using PID by my PID changes every time the app starts

Comment: hint gets id of "pan", watch out for apps with multiple pids like firefox and its download manager as seperate windows

$(pidof pan)

Comment: i didn't get you sorry can you be more elaborate on this

Comment: the processor ID changes on reboot, so you can get the ID# from 


$(pidof <process_name>)

so for firefox for example.


htop -p $(pidof firefox)

works for me.

Comment: you can use `top | grep chromium` for example it will endlessly cast all new and active PIDs for that process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll put it in as an answer because I tested it and it works for me.

the processor ID changes on reboot, so you can get the ID# from

```
$(pidof <process_name>)
```

so for firefox for example.

```
htop -p $(pidof firefox)
```

works for me